# How can I identify which 62 rows are missing values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg,aes(x=displ,y=hwy,shape=class))+geom_point()
#> Warning: The shape palette can deal with a maximum of 6 discrete values because
#> more than 6 becomes difficult to discriminate; you have 7. Consider
#> specifying shapes manually if you must have them.
#> Warning: Removed 62 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

How can I identify which 62 rows are missing values?

Comment: If we look at the legend your plot produces we see that `mpg$class == "suv"` is empty (also double-checking `nrow(mpg[mpg$class == "suv", ])` returns `62`).

Answer (score 0):

You get the first six values from `mpg$class` alphabetically (it if was a factor, this it would be the first six by level). You can find these by converting class first to a factor and then to an numeric and filtering out values greater than six.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>% 
  mutate(class2 = as.numeric(factor(class))) %>% 
  filter(class2 > 6)
#> # A tibble: 62 x 12
#>    manufacturer model displ  year   cyl trans drv     cty   hwy fl    class
#>    <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 chevrolet    c150…   5.3  2008     8 auto… r        14    20 r     suv  
#>  2 chevrolet    c150…   5.3  2008     8 auto… r        11    15 e     suv  
#>  3 chevrolet    c150…   5.3  2008     8 auto… r        14    20 r     suv  
#>  4 chevrolet    c150…   5.7  1999     8 auto… r        13    17 r     suv  
#>  5 chevrolet    c150…   6    2008     8 auto… r        12    17 r     suv  
#>  6 chevrolet    k150…   5.3  2008     8 auto… 4        14    19 r     suv  
#>  7 chevrolet    k150…   5.3  2008     8 auto… 4        11    14 e     suv  
#>  8 chevrolet    k150…   5.7  1999     8 auto… 4        11    15 r     suv  
#>  9 chevrolet    k150…   6.5  1999     8 auto… 4        14    17 d     suv  
#> 10 dodge        dura…   3.9  1999     6 auto… 4        13    17 r     suv  
#> # … with 52 more rows, and 1 more variable: class2 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>